# Count occurrence of words in cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using Microsoft Excel 2013.
I have a entire sentence in one of the cell in my Excel spreadsheet.
I want to count instance of several words in that cell.

Example: Say the sentence "**He** is not doing very well. **His** scores have been dropping consistently over the last few months. **I** spoke to **him** about **his** scores. **I** have also recommended several actions." exists in cell A2.

I want to count the instances of words "he","his","I","him" in the sentence.

So the cell B2 would have a count of 6.

How do I do this?

Comment: Two different approaches using formulas. The more complex one applies to the situation where there may be any number of different punctuation marks within the string (not just full-stops, as in your single example), or where you cannot say for sure what punctuation marks may be present in a given string. The more straightforward solution involves knowing precisely which punctuation marks could be present in a given string, and you providing a definitive list of those punctuation marks. Of course, if, as in your example, we're only ever talking about full-stops, the solution is simple indeed.

Comment: XOR LX - I can parse thorough and replace all punctuation marks from the message. In that case how would the solution look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per XOR LX's suggestion of replacing all punctuation marks, the formula in cell B2 would look like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(" "&A2&" ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" "&LOWER(A2)&" "," "&{"he","his","i","him"}&" ","")))/LEN(" "&{"he","his","i","him"}&" "))
```

Comment: Perfect, tigeravatar! :-)

Comment: Thank you XOR LX and tigeravatar